# Retrieving data to Expandable List View from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, expandablelistview

I'm building a small application that manages users and shifts in Android Studio and I'm using Firebase Database as a back-end.

Users and shifts have a M:M relationship since many users can be assigned to the same shift and a shift can have many users.

This is how my database is structured :

```
{
  "linking" : {
    "shift-assign" : {
      "key1" : {
        "111" : true,
        "222" : true
      },
      "key2" : {
        "111" : true
      }
    },
    "user-assign" : {
      "111" : {
        "key1" : true,
        "key2" : true
      },
      "222" : {
        "key1" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "shifts" : {
    "20191116" : {
      "key1" : {
        "endTime" : "00:00",
        "name" : "Morning",
        "numOfEmps" : 3,
        "startTime" : "00:00",
        "wage" : 0
      },
      "key2" : {
        "endTime" : "00:00",
        "name" : "Night",
        "numOfEmps" : 1,
        "startTime" : "00:00",
        "wage" : 0
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "111" : {
      "id" : "111",
      "password" : "111",
       ...
      },
    "222" : {
      "id" : "222",
      "password" : "222",
      ...
    },
    "99999" : {
      "id" : "99999",
      "password" : "123",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

My application is built such that when a user clicks on a date in the calendar, a `DateActivity` opens up that lists all shifts associated with said date.

I'm using an expandable list to render my data to the user - the header represents a shift (under said date) and its children represent all of the users currently assigned to that shift.

However I'm having a hard time fetching the data from Firebase.

This is my `DateActivity`:

```
public class DateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private String[] dates; // the chosen date and its prior dates
        private List<mShift> shiftList; // parent items of expandable list
        private List<mUser> userList; // child items of expandable list
        private HashMap<mShift, List<mUser>> collection = new HashMap<>(); // mapping parent-children
        private ExpandableListView expListView;
        private mUser user; // store the logged-in user ,to be replaced with user's id

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_date);

            // get user object from shared preferences
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sp", 0);
            String json = sp.getString("user", "");
            user = (new Gson()).fromJson(json, mUser.class);

            // get dates array
            // chosen date in index 0
            // yesterday's date in index 1
            // and so on
            dates = sp.getString("days", "").split(",");

            //bind elements here...

            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);


            // Fetch all shifts for selected date
            fetchShifts();
        }

     private void fetchShifts() {

    // root reference
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    // reference to shifts/dates[0]
    mDatabase.child("shifts")
            .child(dates[0])
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // create a new shift list
            shiftList = new ArrayList<>();

            // loop through all shift objects
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                mShift shift = ds.getValue(mShift.class);
                shift.setKey(ds.getKey());
                shiftList.add(shift); // add shift to list


                // reference to linking/shift-assign/shift-key
                mDatabase.child("linking")
                        .child("shift-assign")
                        .child(shift.getKey())
                        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                // create a new user list
                                userList = new ArrayList<>();

                                // loop through all user objects
                                for(DataSnapshot ds1 : snapshot.getChildren()){

                                    // reference to users/user-id
                                    mDatabase.child("users")
                                            .child(ds1.getKey())
                                            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot2) {
                                                    mUser u = snapshot2.getValue(mUser.class);
                                                    userList.add(u); // add user to list
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                                            });
                                }

                                // map current shift and its users
                                collection.put(shiftList.get(0), userList);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        });
            }

            final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(DateActivity.this, shiftList, collection, dates, user);
            expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

The expandable list is shown but the data is all messed up. Instead of the two users under `key1` I'm only getting the first (whose id is `111`) and under `key2` I should have one user shown but I get none.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is why is the data messed up...